# T-SQL Query to identify varchar fields that consist of a single repeating char/digit?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to clean phone numbers stored as varchar.  There is bad data where unknown phone numbers are stored as a sequence of a single digit.  Eventually more complex (area code & prefix matching) will be done but I want a simply query to obviously bad records.

So for example:

Valid Phone Number:   3289903829

Invalid Phone Number: 1111111111

Now if the bogus Product ID are the proper length ( 10 digits) it is easy to parse and clean.

```
    SELECT phone
    FROM customers 
    SET phone = NULL 
    WHERE phone IN ('0000000000','9999999999',''8888888888','7777777777','6666666666','5555555555','4444444444','3333333333','2222222222','1111111111')
```

However sometimes the bogus phones are of arbitrary length (likely due to typos) so 11 ones or 9 ones, or n ones.
**How can I ID strings that consists of all of the same char/digit?**

```
1111111 - match
4444 - match
1112 - no match
4445555 - no match
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the first character and replicate it:

```
where phone = replicate(left(phone,1), len(phone))
    and phone is not null
```

Comment: You can also use `left(phone,1)` rather than `substring(phone,1,1)`.

Comment: @adrift is left(phone,1) faster than substring(phone,1,1)?  Just curious.

Comment: @theUnhandledException, maybe, but I'd say the greater benefit is that it's a bit clearer

Comment: nice!  You might also want to check to see if the field is numeric.

Comment: @Brandon, good idea - i'll leave it up to the OP whether he wants to use the more general version, or test specifically for all digits vs. all spaces, etc.

Comment: Wonderful - gotta add a clause for NULL / Blank entries too

Comment: All good suggestions in general.  In this instance all fields consists of 1-10 charecters w/ only digits [0 to 9].

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how fast you need it to run, your other option is to populate a temp table and then join your phone number on it.  If you are doing it multiple times, you could even create a real table so you don't have to re-create it each run.  To make it faster you could also index the field.  Your may mileage may vary on fast you need to it to be compared to the number of records you have to compare.

```
CREATE TABLE #Numbers
(
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @run BIT
SET @run = 1

DECLARE @number INT
SET @number = 1

DECLARE @Counter INT 
SET @Counter = 1

WHILE(@run = 1)
BEGIN 

WHILE(@Counter < 13)
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO #Numbers
    SELECT REPLICATE(@number,@counter)

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END


SET @Counter = 1
SET @number = @number + 1

IF(@number > 9)
BEGIN 
    SET @run = 0
END

END

SELECT * FROM Phone p JOIN #numbers n ON p.PhoneNumber = n.PhoneNumber
```

This way you don't have to recalculate the field you are comparing the number to each time.

Comment: As the length of these "special" phone numbers varies, you'd want to do a query `select max(len(phone))` to use instead of `13`.

Comment: that is a good point, actually i would look at the length of the field in the table instead, as technically a phone number could change and the longest phone number might be the one updated.  By looking at the table, you know that you won't have a phone number longer than that.

Comment: Nice solution. +1 I went with the simpler method because in my case it is a "one time" cleanup.  I will be placing constraints to prevent invalid data.  Your method would be the better solution for someone who needs periodic scrubbing of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create a SQL function to do this.

I think the guts of it would look something like this:

```
DECLARE @field varchar(10) 
SET @field = '11111'

DECLARE @len INT
SET @len = LEN(@field)

DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = 1

DECLARE @firstChar VARCHAR(1)
SET @firstChar = NULL

DECLARE @currentChar VARCHAR(1)
SET @currentChar = NULL

DECLARE @allSameNumber BIT
SET @allSameNumber = 1

WHILE @counter <= @len AND @allSameNumber = 1 BEGIN

    SET @currentChar = SUBSTRING(@field,@counter,1) 
    IF @firstChar IS NULL BEGIN
        SET @firstChar = @currentChar
    END 
    IF NOT ISNUMERIC(@currentChar) = 1 OR NOT @currentChar = @firstChar BEGIN
        SET @allSameNumber = 0
    END
    SET @counter = @counter + 1

END

SELECT @allSameNumber
```

Comment: That being said, the replicate solution is far more elegant! I'd probably go with that.